# How can I import a Java package without maven environment?

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I'm using Apache Storm, and following a tutorial of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/storm/apache-storm-develop-java-topology.

I made a Storm environment by running a Storm Docker container.
https://github.com/31z4/storm-docker/blob/9eae4ab08d30cfab29c784b4d9e7d1c187fa0348/2.2.0/Dockerfile

I expect to run Storm tasks immediately.

However, the above tutorial requires maven environment, which is not installed in the docker container by default.

I'm not familiar to maven environment, and I wonder whether there would be another way to run an Apache Storm topology.

Without maven setting, when I compile the codes in the tutorial, errors occurs as:

> error: package org.apache.storm does not exist

How can I import storm packages without using maven?

Any comment appreciated.

Comment: Maven makes life soooooooooooooooo much easier, I recommend you just learn it...

Comment: I also recommend that you just learn Maven especially after the module changes in Java 9 and beyond.

Comment: You *can* do everything Maven does by hand, but it's generally a truly horrible experience. You can always develop locally, create an uber-jar, and deploy that on the container, or just talk to the storm container.

Answer (score 0):

I think alternatively it should be possible for you to download the jar-file from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-core/2.2.0

Just click on files: jar.